# How to speed up this moving algorithm? In Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have an Array of 16 billiard balls in JS and want to move each ball smoothly with its direction and speed.
For that I set up a timer, calling `UpdateThis()` every 42ms (for 24 fps).
The problem is that `UpdateThis()` takes 53ms as firebug states.

Now `UpdateThis` iterates over every ball and calls `UpdateBall(ball)`.
I assume that the problem lies there.
UpdateBall looks like this:

```
function UpdateBall(ball)
{
if(ball.direction.x != 0 && ball.direction.y != 0) {
    //ball moving!
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        //CheckCollision(ball, balls[i]); //even without this it takes 53 ms!
    }

    var ps = VAdd(ball.position, VMul(ball.direction, ball.speed)); //Multiply Direction with speed and add to position!
    if(ps.x < Bx || ps.y < By || ps.x > Bw || ps.y > Bh) { //Bounce off the wall!
        ball.direction = VMul(ball.direction, -1); //Invert direction
        ball.speed *= 1;
        ps = VAdd(ball.position, VMul(ball.direction, ball.speed)); //Calc new position!
    }
    ball.position = ps;
    ball.MoveTo(); //See explanation at the bottom.
    ball.speed *= GRK; //Gravity
    if(ball.speed < 0.05) {
        ball.speed = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

it seems that the most time is spent in `ball.MoveTo()` which looks like this:

```
function() 
{
     this.image.style.left = this.position.x + "px";
     this.image.style.top = this.position.y + "px"; 
}
```

-- UPDATE --

```
function UpdateThis() {
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
         var cur = balls[i];
         UpdateBall(cur);
         balls[i] = cur;
    }
  }
```

and onload looks like

```
nx = setInterval(function() { UpdateThis(); }, 42);
```

Does somebody have any ideas on how to speed this up?

-- UPDATE 2 --

You can download the folder with the HTML file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?fl6i8uaaehtskko) (the password is password)

Comment: When you say you 'assume the problem lies here' and 'it seems that the most time spent...'  Your best bet is to confirm these suspicions first with a profiler.  I know both Firebug and Chrome dev tools have one.

Comment: Yeah I confirmed everything prior to posting it here, but I am still not sure cause I dont see anything that could be slowing this down?

Comment: Which browser are you running this on? Is it Chrome? Firefox? Or maybe IE8 or even 9?

Comment: Did you consider another technique like canvas or SVG(VML for IE)?

Comment: I am running it in Firefox 4. Yes, it has to be only JS and HTML!

Comment: @alex: `VAdd` and `VMul` are also unknown and they may be complex for what we know.

Comment: Please add the UpdateThis() code.  The problem may be there.

Comment: @alex: Why do you reassign balls in `UpdateThis`? Doesn't it work without it? And storing them in `cur` (if things work without reassigning) is pointless because you're *caching* current ball in local function parameter already.

Comment: Vadd and VMul are very simple `function(v,v1) { return new V(v.x + v1.x, v.y + v1.y)`

Comment: Have you tried running with Firebug disabled?  It seems to add a noticeable amount of overhead in my experience.

Comment: @alex: Not necessarily simple, because they do instantiate a new object as seen in your code. Can't you calculate current values and return values instead of allocating new memory by instantiating?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik how could I do that without changing v or v1? I thought of something like `v.x += v1.y; v.y += v1.y; return v;` but I need v unchanged!

Comment: @alex: You may have reasons for that but I don't see why, bacause you're overwriting position in the end anyway.

Comment: the nx interval could be simplified to `nx = setInterval(UpdateThis,42);` but that's not likely going to help with the performance issue.  Any other timers or intervals going on?

Comment: I'll post the folder with the HTML file. You can then test it yourself...

Comment: whats your problem with .rars? you can double check it for viruses if you wish it just contains a html file and some .pngs, nothing that could steal your bank account information...

Comment: @alex: RAR may be fine as long as you've cleaned up your HTML and scripts so they contain the bare minimum what we need to look at. The worst thing is trying to find a needle in a haystack. But it's true that you'd have more developers on this if you've put your HTML and scripts in a JSFiddle. You could of course reference whatever images from the net. We don't need exactly your images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about separating the position updates from the drawing?  So have something like this (untested code):

```
function DrawBall(ball)
{
    ball.MoveTo(); //Take this line out of UpdateBall
}
```

-

```
function UpdateThis() {
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
         var cur = balls[i];
         UpdateBall(cur);
         balls[i] = cur;
    }
}
```

-

```
function DrawThis() {
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
         DrawBall(balls[i]);
    }
    setTimeout(function() { DrawThis(); }, 42);
}
```

-

```
nx = setInterval(function() { UpdateThis(); }, 42);
setTimeout(function() { DrawThis(); }, 42);
```

If indeed it's the moving of the position that's slow, this way the logic update still happens at 42ms, and the framerate is no faster than 42ms but it can skip frames.  (I haven't actually tried this, so this is all theoretical and you may need to tweak some stuff)

Comment: Yeah that looks very nice and the idea of seperating Update and Draw is familiar to me from the XNA framework.

Comment: I'm just implementing it in another HTML file. I'm going to compare it then!

Comment: for me it seems liek there is no difference between the Update only version and the split verison where Draw and Update are seperated?

Comment: Unfortunately it runs too fast on my machine to be able to test it properly.  MoveTo is indeed the slowest call, but it takes an average of 0.168ms and a max of 0.3ms.  What I expect to see is that the speed of the ball movement should still be correct, it's only the drawing that's delayed, but since it all runs at full speed for me, I can't see a difference either.

Comment: But were you able to see how bad the white ball number 16 moves? That looks really terrible... I was able to get a better movement by changing the updating interval to 42ms and the drawing interval to 16ms. Now it looks a little better but not how I want it to be.

Comment: @alex I can't see how bad it looks because it runs full speed without a hitch on my machine.  Overclocked Core i5 CPU, so even with the interval set to 1ms it still updates faster than that (actually 1ms makes it really smooth for me :p)  I'd need a slower computer to test.

Comment: Oh ok i have a Athlon II X4 620 on WinXP running a firefox 4.0.1 without any other tabs and with no add-ons. How is this possible?

Comment: In 1 tab it uses 3% of my cpu... Maybe my frame rate is too low? I'm going to measure it :D

Comment: My computer's just beast, I typically run 3-5 copies of visual studio, SQL server and occasionally a few VMs along with 15-30 browser tabs at the same time without any trouble whatsoever (16GB RAM and a SSD for the OS) so I wouldn't be a typical user to benchmark on.  I'm sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: lol +1 for your system. I think I found the bug! The various framerate seems to cause the ball to move at different speeds, looking terrible... I'll have to take the time in account when calculating the new pos...

Answer (score 2):

### Why moving may be (and most probably is) slow?

Move functionality could be slow, because it has more things to do than simple variable assignment. It has to actually render some element to some other place. You could test this if you run this on IE9. I anticipate it should run faster since it uses hardware video acceleration.

As for the other routine I hope others will dissect it. :)

### Questions for you

1. Can you please describe how do balls move? Sporadically? How do you call `UpdateBall()` for each ball? Do you queue those calls?
2. Provide `VMul` and `VAdd` functionality
3. Have you played with styling? Maybe relative positioning of balls' immediate parent may speed up rendering. And setting `overflow:hidden` on it as well. I don't know. Depends on how you've done it. Hence a JSFiddle would be very helpful.

### A suggestion

Instead of using `setInterval` to call your function you should maybe just queue them and let them execute as fast as it gets. And just for the sake of it, provide a central `setInterval` with some *watcher* that they don't run too fast.

But I guess that it still utilizes your processor to 100% which isn't good anyway.

> **Very important note**: Don't run you app while Firebug's enabled because it's a well known fact that Javascript executes much slower when Firebug is running.

Comment: I am not a fan of IE, and I am not going to install IE9 just to test this. I am just going to believe you :-)

Comment: Since this is strictly DHTML you could quite easily provide a JSFiddle, and someone else could run it for you. And we'd also have our playground to play with and try to optimize individual calls.

Comment: Running the script takes about 15% of my CPU

Comment: I disabled firebug but still have no smooth movement even in a firefox with _no other tabs_

Answer (score 1):

That's tough, if MoveTo() is in fact your bottleneck, since there is not a whole lot going on there.  About the only things I can think of, right off hand, are

1)  Cache the style property of the image and position for faster lookups.  Everytime you see a dot in the object chain it's requires stepping through the scope chain.  Ideally you can cache this property at the time the parent of MoveTo() is constructed.

2)  Are the 'px' strings required? It may result in an invalid CSS specification, but it may still work.  I have a hard time believing 2 string concats would really change all that much though.

The main problem here is likely the fact that anytime you change the DOM, the browsers re-flows the entire page.  Your only other option may be to refactor such that instead of changing the styles, you actually remove the previous contents, and replace it with the a document fragment describing the new state.  This would result in only 2 re-flows for the entire step (1 for removal, 1 for addition), instead of 2 for each ball.

EDIT: Regarding #1 above, when I say cache, I don't mean just locally in the function call.  But perhaps as a closure in the parent object.  For example:

```
var Ball = function(img){
    var style = img.style;
    var posX;
    var posY;

    function MoveTo(){
        style.left = posX + "px";
        style.right = posY + "px"; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Caching didn't change anything, but thanks for making the effort :D

Comment: I'm guessing it's a reflow issue then, based on the data you've provided thus far

Comment: You could download the file and try to test your own ideas, then you can share them with us. How could I find out if that "px" is really required?